# Bootstrap theme using Php to send email form error

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have this html code for the form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post"  id="form" class="form" role="form">

    <h4 class="form-heading">Luxury at an affordable price</h4>

    <div class="form-validation alert"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form-name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="form-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form-email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="form-email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Valid Email Address" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form-phone">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="phone" name="phone" id="form-phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Valid Phone Number" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form-info">Package</label>
        <p>
            <select type="info" name="info" id="form-info" class="form-control">
                <option value="Diamond">Diamond</option>
                <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
                <option value="silver">Silver</option>
                <option value="silver">Custom</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form-pax"># of People</label>
        <input type="pax" name="pax" id="form-pax" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of People in your Party" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form-com">Comments</label>
        <input type="com" name="com" id="form-com" class="form-control" placeholder="Additional Comments" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-submit">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-loading-text="Action Button">More Info</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And also i have this Php code:

```
<?php 
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['info'])    ||
   empty($_POST['pax']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Your data is not valid!");</script>';
    return false;
   }
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$info = $_POST['info'];
$pax= $_POST['pax'];
$com= $_POST['com'];
// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'rubengallardo.88@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Contacto de cancunprivateparty.com : $name";
$email_body = "Nuevo mensaje del formulario de Cancún Private Party.\n\n"."Estos son los detalles:\n\nNombre: $name\n\nEmail: $email\n\nTel: $phone\n\nPaquete: $info \n\n # de Pax: $pax \n\n Comentarios: $com"  ;
$headers = "From: noreply@cancunprivateparty.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.\n\n Comentarios: $com
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Your message has been sent!");</script>';
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.cancunprivateparty.com">';

return true;    


 ?>
```

When i fill the form and send the email i get a error that says "your data is not valid" even if my data is valid.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` should lead you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

is your `<form>` tag missing?
Works fine for me when set:

contact.html

```
                   <form method="post" action="contact_form.php">
                            <h4 class="form-heading">Luxury at an affordable price</h4>

                                <div class="form-validation alert"></div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form-name">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="form-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Full Name" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form-email">Email Address</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="form-email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Valid Email Address" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form-phone">Phone Number</label>
                                    <input type="phone" name="phone" id="form-phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Valid Phone Number" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>  
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form-info">Package</label>
                                    <p>
                                    <select type="info" name="info" id="form-info" class="form-control">
                                     <option value="Diamond">Diamond</option>
                                     <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
                                     <option value="silver">Silver</option>
                                     <option value="silver">Custom</option>
                                     </select>
                                    </p>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form-pax"># of People</label>
                                    <input type="pax" name="pax" id="form-pax" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of People in your Party" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>  
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form-com">Comments</label>
                                    <input type="com" name="com" id="form-com" class="form-control" placeholder="Additional Comments" autocomplete="off">
                                </div>  
                                <div class="form-group form-group-submit">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-loading-text="Action Button">More Info</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

contact_form.php

```
<?php 
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['info'])    ||
   empty($_POST['pax']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Your data is not valid!");</script>';
    return false;
   }

    echo "yes";

return true;    


 ?>
```